# Habilitar un botón

Tags: java, android-studio, app, checkbox

estoy creando una aplicación móvil, en la cual al activar un Checkbox se me habilite un botón, pero si el Checkbox no está activado el botón esté inhabilitado, cómo puedo hacer que funcione?, muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Hasta ahora qué has probado, qué tienes hecho? Muestra algo. No esperes que se te de la solución.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes implementar el listener del checkbox y cada vez que cambie de estado, habilitar o desabilitar el botón ejecutando algo como:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setEnabled(false);
```

Así, cada vez que pulses en el checkbox en función de su estado, activar el bótón o no con true o false en setEnabled.